# What is wrong with my Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I am trying to understand how genetic algorithms work. As with everything, I learn by attempting to write something on my own;however, my knowledge is very limited and I am not sure if I am doing this right.

The purpose of this algorithm is to see how long it will take half of a herd to be infected by a disease if half of that population are already infected. It is just an example I came up with in my head so I am not sure if this would even be a viable example.

Some feedback on how I can improve my knowledge would be nice.

Here is the code:

```
import random

def disease():
    herd = []
    generations = 0
    pos = 0
    for x in range(100):
        herd.append(random.choice('01'))
    print herd
    same = all(x == herd[0] for x in herd)
    while same == False:
        same = all(x == herd[0] for x in herd)
        for animal in herd:
            try:
                if pos != 0:
                    after = herd[pos+1]
                    before = herd[pos-1]
                    if after == before and after == '1' and before == '1' and animal == '0':
                        print "infection at", pos
                        herd[pos] = '1'
            #print herd
                pos += 1
            except IndexError:
                pass
        pos = 0
        generations += 1
        random.shuffle(herd)
        #print herd
    print "Took",generations,"generations to infect all members of herd."
if __name__ == "__main__":
    disease()
```

I am looking for comments based on the logic of this algorithm. What can be improved, and what has to be improved to make this a true genetic algorithm if it isn't one already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your algorithm is not a genetic algorithm, it is a simple model of infection.

genetic algorithm normally uses at least the following concepts: **inheritance**, **mutation**, **selection** (or fitness).
see, e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)

if - for the sake of introductory understanding - you want to apply these concepts to your example:

- **inheritance**:
  *conceptual*: you need a *genetic identity* of your unit (the animal).
  *code*: i.e. you need animals with state, different instances.
  *how*: each animal inherits this *genetic identity* to the next generation when it is reproduced.
- **mutation**:
  *conceptual*: each generation is slightly different from the other.
  *code*: each animal in a new generation has slightly different values than its parent.
  *how*: apply some random modification.
- **selection** of fitness:
  *conceptual*: you select which units are reproduced for the next generation by the differences between the units. choose the fittest.
  *code*: when assembling the new generation, choose only those units for reproduction that satisfy a certain fitness limit (e.g. the best 90%).
  *how*: define a *fitness-function* which returns a value indicating relative fitness for each unit.

to put it together, you could make e.g. different herds of animals that have different starting values for the 'genetic' attributes (e.g. preferred_proximity_to_next_animal, skin_color, height, aggressiveness, etc
.).
Then, in your *fitness function*, you define how each of the attributes is connected to fitness, i.e. how they are related to the probability to get infected. then let the program run for a some of generations and see how at each iteration the global probability of infection decrease in relation to the genetic setup of your herd.

Like that you might find favourable combinations of attributes.
Generally, genetic algorithms are used in [search-related problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm#Problem_domains).

Answer (score 3):

```
import random

def disease():
    herd = []
    generations = 0
    pos = 0
```

Don't assign variables ahead of their use

```
    for x in range(100):
        herd.append(random.choice('01'))
    print herd
    same = all(x == herd[0] for x in herd)
    while same == False:
        same = all(x == herd[0] for x in herd)
```

Firstly, don't check for `== False`, use `not`. Also, there isn't any point in storing it in same, just test it:

```
 while not all(x == herd[0] for x in herd):
```

I'd suggest testing using:

```
while len(set(herd)) != 1:
```

Which will be more efficient.

```
        for animal in herd:
            try:
                if pos != 0:
                    after = herd[pos+1]
                    before = herd[pos-1]
                    if after == before and after == '1' and before == '1' and animal == '0':
```

There is no point in checking if `after == before` if you are already checking that after and before are both equal to '1'. I'd consider doing:

```
if (after, animal, before) == ('1','0','1'):
```

which in this case I think shows more clearly what's going on.

```
                        print "infection at", pos
                        herd[pos] = '1'
            #print herd
                pos += 1
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

Its generally not a good idea to catch an IndexError. Its too easy to get an accidental IndexError and then have your code miss the real problem. It also doesn't communicate why you are getting an index error.

Instead of updating pos, I suggest you use

```
for pos, animal in enumerate(herd):
```

However, since you don't want the first and last elements anyways, I'd suggest

```
 for pos in xrange(1, len(herd) - 1):
     before, animal, after = herd[pos-1,pos+2]
```

Back to your code:

```
        pos = 0
```

You should reset things just before a loop, not afterwards. That way its easier to follow. Although its even better if you can avoid the resting altogether

```
        generations += 1
        random.shuffle(herd)
        #print herd
    print "Took",generations,"generations to infect all members of herd."
if __name__ == "__main__":
    disease()
```

Comment: This was an amazing response. Thank you for breaking down my code, it was really informative.

Answer (score 1):

Extract methods `initHerd`, `processGeneration` and  `infect`.